# XAML Listpicker template in fullscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

I'm having problem with the template applied to my Fullscreen items page, when I use the default one in Listpicker Fullscreen mode, the text is displayed correctly but the font size is too small, so I apply my own template but I can't get the text to display, although if I click in the empty space of the new Fullscreen Page, I can see there was an Item selected because it returns with a SelectedItem and the event SelectionChanged is fired.

So here was my XAML displaying correctly the items:

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="LpBluetoothPaired" Margin="75,32,252,532"     SelectionChanged="LpBluetoothPaired_SelectionChanged" Tap="LpBluetoothPaired_Tap" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate/>
```

now here it is with a template applied to it, but the text is not shown, although the orange background is seen:

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="LpBluetoothPaired" Margin="75,32,252,532" SelectionChanged="LpBluetoothPaired_SelectionChanged" Tap="LpBluetoothPaired_Tap" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16 21 0 20" Background="Orange" Width="110" Height="110" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

I'm new to XAML and WPF so I imagine this must be something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change Text binding from :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" .../>
```

To this :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" .../>
```